# Pdfptable cuts into page while using three tables and WriteSelectedRows

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, pdfptable

While using PdfPTable by iTextsharp, we are facing an issue where the scenario is 
that there are three tables added one after the other in a document such as:

```
tblEstimate.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 15, 675, cb); // cb : PdfContentByte
tblEstimate0.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 15, 625, cb); // cb : PdfContentByte
tblEstimate1.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 15, 800, cb); // cb : PdfContentByte
```

The issues is that while the two of the three methods above, prints the table well, but the third one having multiple rows with lots of data get stretched up and the elongated table gets cut off the page rather than continuing to the next page. See the screenshot.

[image]

I want the table to be split in another page rather then cut off the current page. We have tried a lot yet with no luck, any prompt help in this matter will be highly useful. Regards.

Comment: If you use `WriteSelectedRows()`, **you** are responsible for doing the math, making the rows fit on the page, and cutting the table in two or more to distribute it over different pages. I don't know where you found out about the `WriteSelectedRows()` method, but if it's on an official place, and if you had read the accompanying text, you wouldn't have had to ask this question. If you want to position a `PdfPTable` at an absolute position, and still delegate some control of the layout to iText, you should add the table to a `ColumnText` instance instead of using `WriteSelectedRows()`.

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie thanks for the comments, well can't say exactly who and when someone used such code, while the thing is when I use document.Add method and add the above three tables, then the table prints nicely to new pages until the table and related rows end, but in that situation, I am having a situation where I am unable to print page numbers for each of that generated page added by document.add, My code have CreateFooter methods and incremental page number after each document.NewPage()

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to print page numbers in case you use `document.Add(table)`? Have you ever heard about page events? It seems to me that you try to safe time skipping the documentation, then waste plenty of time because of wrong design choices. Is that a correct assessment of the problem?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie , I completely honour documentation, yet the thing is that the project is currently live and I am new at it, someone has written it previously and it is highly integrated in the code, If I change the design it will effect the whole. I have definitely used page event method for printing pages in an another task, but here is this task the page number is accompanying with footer having dynamic text from variables, until I know the PdfPageEventHelper methods accepts arguments such as PdfWriter and Document.

Comment: You don't use `PdfPageEventHelper` as such because all the methods in `PdfPageEventHelper` are empty. You *extend* `PdfPageEventHelper`, and since **you** extend that class, **you** decide whether or not it accepts arguments. See for instance [How to generate a report with dynamic header in PDF using itextsharp?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-generate-report-dynamic-header-pdf-using-itextsharp).

Comment: Of course, if you want to continue using absolute positioning, please take a look at listing 4.23 and figure 4.16 in [chapter 4 of my book](http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/adding-a-table-at-an-absolute-position-itext-5/). It's up to you to make the design that best meets your needs (but you need to use the right classes and methods).

Comment: Thanks honourable Bruno Lowagie, it will definitely help. Will update the question one's its done.